# apparent Obsolescence in Apple Xcode and Swift

Tags: macos, xcode, swift

am desperately trying to develop in Xcode, Swift, and particularly SwiftUI.

have perfectly good (and incredibly expensive) Apple hardware that is now about 8 to 10 years old.

apparently this means i cannot upgrade the operating system past 10.15.7 (Catalina)

and apparently this means i cannot upgrade Xcode past 11.4

which leaves me with Swift 5.2

which apparently leaves me in Apple's dust, where many parts of Xcode and Swift - and particularly SwiftUI - are immature at best, and hopelessly incomplete, in my position.

it cannot be possible that Apple expects me to replace thousands of dollars in hardware just to get menus (for example) to work, surely?

and yet, according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu, i need OS 11.0 or better, for this feature.

what am i not understanding?

how do i get there from here?

Comment: Can’t you keep building the same software you did 10 years ago with this setup? To me obsolescence means you can’t do the same things over time and not that all new development SDK and hardware capabilities are back ported / emulated / supported on old gear and old OS. That would be forward compatibility in my book…

Comment: my software was created to support a legacy protocol, about 25 years ago, and remains portable, and POSIX standard, to this day.  my source compiles without warning on every platform our user base requires.

Comment: If your source code compiled on every platform you need to support, why worry about Swift menus? Can‘t you just keep going with what you have?

Comment: I think you have valid points and a superb grasp of development. This reads a lot like a "whinge" though so I expect it will receive a poor vote reception here as many won't see a practical problem to be solved as opposed to opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a good understanding.

Yes, it is common for Apple (and many other companies) to only support their software on hardware that is relatively recent. The successor to macOS Catalina is macOS Big Sur, which supports the Pro Macs that date back to 2013.

If you have a 2012 or earlier model when writing software for 2022, it does seem reasonable to think about upgrading the hardware.

If you haven't got the option of upgrading your hardware, you could look into one of the [various](https://github.com/barrykn/big-sur-micropatcher) [patchers](https://github.com/StarPlayrX/bigmac) available that makes it possible to install Big Sur on even older hardware. As a developer, I wouldn't advise doing so though, as you can't really be sure if issues you run into are caused by your unsupported setup or bugs in your code.

Another possibility is to run Big Sur in a virtual machine on your Catalina Mac. That doesn't require any patchers, but comes with it own set of drawbacks. Most notably, on a 10 year old Mac it will probably be a bit slow.

Yes, various Xcode version requires various operating system versions. The reasoning here is that if you're writing software that requires new OS feature, then the developer needs to be running such a new operating system in order to actually run the software.

For professional software developers in most parts of the world, a cost of a few thousand dollars in hardware depreciated over *10 years* is really not a big deal. I.e.

Finally, no it is not so that getting menus to work requires you to spend thousands of dollars on hardware. Only getting menus to work using that one specific method requires you to have Big Sur. You can get menus working in Swift applications in many other ways that won't require Big Sur. Note that you have lots of applications running on Catalina (and older) that have menus - so it's not impossible.

Comment: am linux, and if we can do it... had hoped Apple might be different, ah well.  anything else i might say would be political, probably not appropriate here.  thank you very much for letting me know.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence "am linux, and if we can do it"? I'm a Linux software developer myself, but not sure what Linux has to do with this. If you want, you can run Linux on the old Mac if that's the question.

Comment: and unfortunately i don't understand how you could develop in linux, and not notice that everything remains portable, on any suitable hardware.  the fact that SwiftUI cannot do menus in Catalina is entirely down to corporate choices, it has nothing to do with the hardware.  this is deliberate obsolescence and, to me, it is obscene.  yes, if this were my hardware, i would install linux, however my company remain committed to apple, and unfortunately i must live with it.  i think this is now a political issue, and i hope i'm not out of line here.

Comment: I don't see why you need to spend thousands of dollars - get a refurbed laptop for $850 for a build machine, or an M1 Mac Mini for under $600.  https://www.apple.com/shop/refurbished/mac  For required xcode releases, this site is helpful: https://xcodereleases.com  And it's not political, Apple has been obsoleting their hardware for decades.  Sad, but true.  And "portability" on Linux always seemed to me that you needed the latest and greatest library, apps, support tools to build anything without errors... which is why I got tired of playing sys-admin and switched to a Mac in 2002.  :-)

Comment: thank you for "Apple has been obsoleting their hardware for decades", confirms my worst fears, and i needed to know.  cannot do anything about the hardware my people choose, and then waste, can only weep.  and it is political, unfortunately, "there is no planet B", obsoleting is a terrible evil.